# Set EXE VersionInfo

Tags: windows, delphi, exe, patch, versioninfo

The information on the version Exe-file I receive by means of [VerQueryValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647464%28VS.85%29.aspx). Is there an inverse function (WinApi or Delphi) which can register (establish or change) such information?
Here, for example, there is a program which is able to do so. How may it work ([http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/))?

Comment: This is determined by the [version resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381058(VS.85).aspx). Use [`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049(VS.85).aspx) to modify it.

Comment: Here's a link to a program with source how to set the version info. Delphi 2009 and up compatible. [updated-setversion-exe-to-set-file-version-info-in-res-or-exe](http://www.jasontpenny.com/blog/2009/09/05/updated-setversion-exe-to-set-file-version-info-in-res-or-exe/)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The version information is stored via resources; to edit that you simply need to edit that resource. Here is a unit I found that can clone an existing file version information and attach it to another file. It's very easy to do what you want starting from this code (it's coded by a friend of mine and is available public):

```
unit cloneinfo;

interface

uses Windows, SysUtils;

type
 LANGANDCODEPAGE = record
  wLanguage: Word;
  wCodePage: Word;
 end;

procedure clone(sFile,output:string);

implementation

procedure clone(sFile,output:string);
var
  dwHandle, cbTranslate: cardinal;
  sizeVers: DWord;
  lpData, langData: Pointer;
  lpTranslate: ^LANGANDCODEPAGE;
  hRes : THandle;
begin
 sizeVers := GetFileVersionInfoSize(PChar(sFile), dwHandle);
 If sizeVers = 0 then
 exit;
 GetMem(lpData, sizeVers);
 try
  ZeroMemory(lpData, sizeVers);
  GetFileVersionInfo (PChar(sFile), 0, sizeVers, lpData);
  If not VerQueryValue (lpData, '\VarFileInfo\Translation', langData, cbTranslate) then
  exit;
  hRes := BeginUpdateResource(pchar(output), FALSE);
  //For i := 0 to (cbTranslate div sizeof(LANGANDCODEPAGE)) do
  //begin
  lpTranslate := Pointer(Integer(langData) + sizeof(LANGANDCODEPAGE));
  UpdateResource(hRes, RT_VERSION, MAKEINTRESOURCE(VS_VERSION_INFO), lpTranslate^.wLanguage,lpData, sizeVers);
  //end;
  EndUpdateResource(hRes, FALSE);
 finally
  FreeMem(lpData);
 end;
end;


end.
```

Comment: It's just for language and code page information. What about [VS_FIXEDFILEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646997%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) ? +1 anyway

Comment: If this is a unit that you found on the Internet, you need to be more careful with the licensing. At the very, very least, you should provide a link to the source. (In addition, have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-on_sentence.)

Comment: @opc0de, all well and good for you, but without a statement from the author saying that it's free to use, it's "found on the internet" for the rest of us.  Upvote pending resolution....

Comment: @Chris In order to get rid of the license, it is very easy to recode it from scratch to get your own version (using an array of bytes instead of a pointer+getmem+zeromemory+freemem for instance). It is just a wrapper around Windows API. Nice code in all cases. +1

Comment: I usually don't copy and paste code but calling some api's i don't think should be in the incidence of a copyright if this was an algorithm or something hard to do i would agree.As Arnaud pointed i could cut some apis or replace them with synonyms and voila code written by me.

Comment: @opc0de, arnand, understood. +1